# Azure APIM custom domain SSL let's encrypt

Tags: ssl, dns, lets-encrypt, azure-api-management

I want to create a SSL certificate for a custom domain I owned and I then need to use this certificate with an Azure APIM instance.
I found the steps to assign a custom domain in APIM but I missed 2 pre-requisities:
  - The SSL certificat that needs to be uploaded first to a key vault --> I'm looking for the how to guid to use let's encrypt to generate this certificate
  - The DNS configuration that is required for APIM (only a CNAME?)

Comment: I do not understand your question but it is not necessary to upload it to key vault you can select custom and upload your certificate to your Azure APIM directly.

Comment: Ok you are right, I can upload directly the certificate in APIM without a KeyVault. But in fact my question is mostly about the certificate itself and the DNS.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways/tools that you can use to generate SSL certificates using Let's Encrypt.

[`acme.sh`](https://github.com/Neilpang/acme.sh) is a personal favorite which is `bash` compatible and supports DNS-01 [challenges](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/) with lots of providers ([Azure DNS](https://github.com/Neilpang/acme.sh/wiki/dnsapi#37-use-azure-dns) is one of them).

Once you generate the cert (you can find them under ~/.acme.sh/), convert it to `.pfx` using this command

```sh
openssl pkcs12 -export -out domain.name.pfx -inkey domain.name.key -in domain.name.crt
```

Now you could either upload this file to Key Vault and reference it in APIM or directly upload it as well.

> Note that LE certs expire in [90 days](https://letsencrypt.org/2015/11/09/why-90-days.html) which acme.sh [renews](https://github.com/Neilpang/acme.sh#12-how-to-renew-the-certs) every 60 days and can be done manually as well.
>
> Also, you will have to convert and reupload the new certs into Key Vault as well

As for the DNS entry, yes, you just need a CNAME record.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding acme.sh, what is the mode I need to use to generate the certificate? The standalone mode?

Comment: It would depend on how'd you want to ensure that the certificate is valid. If you have a server to spare (and its 80 port) standalone mode is good. You could also use the Apache and Nginx modes as applicable. Personally, I use the DNS Mode.